# How to create a template with contact info in Windows Live Mail?

Tags: email, templates, windows-live-mail

Is it possible to create a template to use in Windows Live mail which I can load peoples details into from my contact list?

I currently send emails to people but I have to manually view them in the address book, then copy there details into an email.

What I would like is to open the template, select the email address and everything else is auto completed, such as first name, address etc. These would go in set fields which I set within the template.

Is this possible? I am willing to switch to another mail account if needed but I would prefer it to be in Windows Live Mail. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct ms-word mail merge utility with any email client, not sure of outlook :(.

The best I can suggest is to generate a mail merged files from word, open them with live mail and just send.

Issues:

1. Recipient details (`to:xyz@abc.com`) had to add manually.
2. Content might have to paste manually

Another solution is to write a simple utility which will replace place holders in a template file and send them using SMTP. If you are aware of any programming language then it is really simple.